# C# HttpClient freeze in SendAsync

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I have C# class liblary .NET Framework 4.7.2 who run as plugin for cashbox system(iikofront) in new process.

In work flow program call HTTPS API in Internet.
That http request code
[image]

In plugin logs:

```
[INFO] 2020-10-20 13:40:23 Start SendAsync  
[INFO] 2020-10-20 13:40:45 End SendAsync
```

In server load balancer:

```
2020-10-20 13:40:34 Start process request
2020-10-20 13:40:36 End process request
```

**PROBLEM**
HTTP Request come in server after 10-12 seconds and exist cases when delay 20-30 seconds and Request was abort by HttpClient Timeout. This behavior repeat for first http request, rest requests handled without delay.

**QUESTION**
What could be the reason for the delay?

**INFORMATION**
Internet connection fast check in browser
Behavior not repeat in browser if call GET request in browser adress field

HttpClient is created for every request by this code:

```
public class HttpClientFactory
{
    public static HttpClient Get()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient(
            new HttpClientHandler
            {
                MaxConnectionsPerServer = 100
            })
        {
            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)
        };

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "ru");

        return client;
    }
}
```

Comment: `HttpClient is created for every request by this code` - not related to your problem, but you [should not do that](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/). Actually, it could be related to your problem if there is throttling of number of simultaneous connections.

Comment: Its not a good idea to create a fresh Http client per request. See https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: Create a class variable as static that will contain instance of httpclient

Comment: Have you checked this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: It can be related to multiple `HttpClient`'s or limited number of requests allowed per host by default. A little bit more info and links you can find in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61957805/2501279)

Comment: Please don't post code as an image. Text is always preferred.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyClass
{

    static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    //..rest of code
}
```

The instance created using static readonly modifiers will create one instance that will be valid throughout the application lifecycle and will not be modifiable.

Comment: Please add explanation how it would solve OP's problem.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that. I have added some. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in `MaxConnectionsPerServer`. `HttpClientHandler` does not send a request if `MaxConnectionsPerServer` limit is reached, but `Timeout` starts to work from the moment of calling `httpClient.SendAsync`.

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar issue where I was loosing the HttpContext on async calls. The fix was to add

```
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
```

to the app settings in web.config. The post on SO is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64371054/tokenclient-requestauthorizationcodetokenasync-is-clearing-out-httpcontext-can).

Comment: I have C# class liblary .NET Framework 4.7.2 not asp.net application